# Scripting.Dictionary.this[ref object]' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#

I am converting a VB6 project to C# .Net but I have problems using `Scripting.Dictionary`. The error message is **" Scripting.Dictionary.this[ref object]' is not supported by the language "**. I want to get the item for a specific key.

```
key=astr[n];
Scripting.Dictionary m_dicValueOf;
strXPath = m_dicValueOf[astr[n]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ref` or `out` parameters in an indexer in C#, so you can't use an indexer that has a `ref` or `out` parameter.

(The reasoning behind the limitation in the language is of course that it makes no sense what so ever to change the key that you send to an indexer.)

Use the `Dictionary<K,V>` class from the framework instead. Example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> m_dicValueOf;

strXPath = m_dicValueOf[key];
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the `dictionary[ref key]` on the surface looks like a C# indexer it is not compatible.

Instead, to set a value in the dictionary you need to use the underlying set method:

```
dictionary.set_Item(ref key, value);
```

Note that the type of `key` has to be `Object`.

To get a value for a key you need to use the underlying get method:

```
var value = dictionary.get_Item(ref key);
```

Again, `key` has to be `Object`.